# what is run-parts in /etc/crontab, and how do I use it

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I have been digging through my Linux system. To try and understand how it all works

In the /etc/crontab file. I see the following

```
# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

What is run-parts, what does it do, and how can I use it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Basically, [`run-parts(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/debianutils/run-parts.8.en.html) takes a directory as an argument.

It will run every script that is found in this directory. For example, if you do a listing of `/etc/cron.hourly`, you'll see that it's a directory where you can put executable files to be run every hour.

As you can see, in `cron` it's used for convenience, since you only have to specify one directory and everything in that directory will be executed. This makes it easy to maintain scripts in one of the `etc/cron*` directories.

See its manpage for more options that could be exploited for your own use cases. You could for example do a simple check and show which scripts would be run:

```sh
run-parts -v --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

*The `-v` flag might not be available everywhere.*

Comment: What is the `root` portion for?

Comment: @jakenoble `root` means that the command (`run-parts` in this case) will be run as root user

Comment: Note that on CentOS (at least el5) run-parts is a bash script that doesn't have any options so you will get "-v is not a directory". Or at least that's what it shown me on my system.

Comment: CentOS probably got the idea from Debian but reimplemented it independently. There are many Linux distros which do not have this mechanism, too.